# FirebaseException only thrown when GetOptions(source: Source.server)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, exception, google-cloud-firestore

When requesting Firestore data using my flutter app without network connection, I would expect a FirebaseException when the data is not cached already.

Example:

```
try {
  return await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("songs").get();
} on FirebaseException catch (e) {
  log(e.toString());
  return null;
}
```

But this never happens.  `get()` returns a QuerySnapshot with an empty list of documents instead. Note: I just removed the cached data from the device, so there shouldn't exist any cached documents.

When explicitly requesting the data only from server, then the exception is thrown as expected:

```
try {
  return await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("songs")
      .get(GetOptions(source: Source.server);
} on FirebaseException catch (e) {
  log(e.toString());
  return null;
}
```

Is this expected behavior? My client shouldn't even know if this collection exists. How should the client distinguish between a failed network request and a successful request, but with an empty collection on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To distinguish a **failed network request with no documents of the collection in cache** from a **successful network request with an empty collection on server**, you can use the `isFromCache` property of the Snapshot which is returned by the `get()` method. Thanks to Frank van Puffelen!

The following workaround solves this problem for me:

```
final snapshot = return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("songs").get();
if (snapshot.docs.isEmpty && snapshot.metadata.isFromCache) {
  return null;
} else {
  return snapshot;
}
```

**...but not for 100%**, which if fine for my app. I think this is just a limitation of caching. You never know if the data in cache is really up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

> How should the client distinguish between...

I usually find it easier to solve this type of problem by changing that question to a "Why". So: why should the client distinguish between a failed network request and a successful request, but with an empty collection on the server?

Usually this is because you're looking to write/update a document, and there may be conflicting writes from different users. In such scenarios you should likely [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions), which then also solves the problem of getting a false non-existing document snapshot, as the transaction will auto-retry in cases when that happens.

Comment: Thanks for the transaction reminder, forgot about this feature! But in my case, I would answer the "why" a bit different: The client needs to know, when a network request failed to show a placeholder text with a retry button. If the requested collection is just empty on the server, then the list on the client should be also just empty and/or show a different placeholder.

Comment: As more as I think about it, I get to the point that this is probably just a small limitation of caching I have to accept. Even when I have some docs of the collection in cache, I can't be sure that the list is complete without magic.

A workaround that I can think of would be by using `GetOptions(source: Source.server)` first and if this throws an exception, it could retry the request with `GetOptions(source: Source.cache)`. At least this would tell the client if the server request failed first.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there's a way to detect this in the read operation (I might be wrong there, so definitely check for any metadata you can find). I'd typically detect offline/online state in a write operation based on the `isCached` and `hasPendingWrites` properties of https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.SnapshotMetadata.